# Portainer - no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries - install error

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2016, portainer

I have tried executing below command to run portainer.

In Native Windows containers. Windows Server 2016 Datacenter.

$ docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 --name portainer --restart always -v \.\pipe\docker_engine:\.\pipe\docker_engine -v C:\ProgramData\Portainer:C:\data portainer/portainer

[image]

This is the error I am getting, "no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries."

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hi pl run docker pull portainer/portainer and see if it runs successfully. Hope docker service port (`default 2375`) is allowed on windows firewall